# Why I'm unable to update MySql table via Java Application(netbeans)?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Here is the code I'm using(The MySql table isn't getting updated and the statement system.out.print("error"); is working and "error" is shown written in output window):

```
 try {

    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ghyrdkl";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"abcxyz","xyzabc");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from feedback;");
rs.last(); int  d = rs.getInt("id");

int idvariable = ++d; String namevariable = nametf.getText(); int starsvariable = Integer.parseInt(starsl.getText()); String wordsvariable = wordsta.getText();
String insert="INSERT INTO feedback VALUES('"+idvariable+"','"+namevariable+"'"+starsvariable+"','"+wordsvariable+"');";
       stmt.executeUpdate(insert);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.print("error");
    }
```

Comment: Show `System.out.print("error: " + e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 0):

Changes don't show up in the database until you [commit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#commit_transactions).

```
stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
con.commit(); // exception may occur, prepare to handle SQLException!
```

However, that's not why you're having a problem.

The value `'"+idvariable+"'` is a string value. PResumably, `idVariable` is supposed to be an integer. If the column is not a numeric type, you'll get a type error, which explains the error print message.

There may be other problems that cannot be diagnosed without the actual exception that's being thrown. Instead of `System.out.print("error")` consider `e.printStackTrace();`